# Given the following class definition and lines of code

Tags: c++

I'm continuing to study for my C++/OOP exam, but it's been a while since I've worked with C++, so I need a bit of help please. Thank you!!

Here is the question:

Given the following class definition and lines of code, what would be displayed if Line 6 were replaced by: cout << d2.getFeet() << endl;

```
class Distance
{
private:
int feet;
double inches;
public:
Distance( );
Distance(int initFt, double initIn);
void setFeet(int feetIn);
void setInches(double inchesIn);
int getFeet() const;
double getInches( ) const;
};
int main( )
{
Distance d1; //Line 1
const int MAX = 100; //Line 2
Distance list[MAX]; //Line 3
Distance d2(1, 2.3); //Line 4
Distance * pDist; //Line 5
d1.feet = 5; //Line 6
// etc. – assume the remaining code is correct
}
```

> Possible answers: 0, 1, 2.3, 5

Comment: Do you have any compiler at home ? Or are you in the exam room ?

Comment: There really is no way to know, because we can't see the definition of `Distance::getFeet()`. And the code wouldn't compile anyway.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I do have a compiler, but like juanchopanza said, it doesn't compile...

Comment: Possible answers: 0,
1,
2.3,
5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of `getFeet()` isnt defined, but given that it returns an `int`, and the `feet` member of d2 was most recently set to "1", assuming the missing code meakes sense, the printout would be "1".

Comment: I'm finding out quickly that whoever writes these tests really doesn't know what they're doing enough to be writing tests for students.

Comment: @user3850431 You're welcome. And I agree that if this is indeed what you were given, it's quite incomplete and really should contain more information.